# I Changed the Menu Order, But the Page Order Didn't Change on Front Page

Tags: pages, order, menu-order

First-timer here! I'm trying to change the order of pages on my boardgame webpage, as displayed on the top banner [www.mangakagame.com](http://www.mangakagame.com) .

Basically, I've used "Edit" in the Dashboard and adjusted all the "order" attributes, but nothing changes. It's still using chronological ordering. The "Simple Page Ordering" plugin didn't do anything either.

Weirder still, I tried to set one of the pages to "Private" but it still shows up in the banner! :/ It just links to an "Oops! That page can not be found." So I had to set it to public again, at least temporarily...

I assume this may be due to something in the WP theme I'm using (Auberge), but I can't figure it out. If this requires fiddling with the actual CSS, I don't even know where to begin. If anyone has any suggestions, I'd be super grateful.

Many thanks,

Jason (@mockman)

Comment: Welcome.  Does that theme have 'menus'  under appearance? One of the less than ideal aspects (imho) of the menu customiser is that there can now be quite a disconnect between what the page ordering and parent structure says, and what is happening in the menu setup.  There is some defaulting that can happen where top level pages are automatically added to the menu, but other maintenance is not reflected.  In my opinion, if a user does not create a menu, the page structure should be it, however a theme can do its own thing. Check the menu's.

Answer (score -1):

By default, posts and pages are sorted after the date. If you want sort pages by "order" field, which is visible on edit page, you have to set `orderby` parameter:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'change_order');

function change_order($query) {
    if ( is_front_page() || is_home() ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'menu_order' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Put code in `functions.php` file. 
More about **orderby** parameters you will find [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Unfortunately, I cut and pasted that text into functions.php, but it didn't do anything... the "Auberge" theme which I'm using seems to have a very minimal functions.php, so maybe that has something to do with it?